# How to pass class attribute to child component element

Tags: vue.js

how can I pass class attribute from parent to child component element?

Look here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-shamir-1wuuv

I'm adding class to the Component "Input Field"
[image]

And my goal is that the 'custom-class' will be implemented on the 'input' element in the child component
[image]

But just still using the class attribute, and not setting a new prop like "customClass" and accept it in the props of the component

Thanks!

Comment: do you want all props to go to the input element? also the v-model and any event binding? If yes, then the Vue 2 doc for that should be this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Answer (score 8):

I'm late to the party, but I wanted to share my solution because none of the above answers is what I was looking for.
Of course, you could pass this class as a prop using another name than the reserved `class` keyword (e.g. `classes`), but if you are building a library for instance, where you want to allow the built-in HTML `class` attribute, this is how I have done it.

If you want to add the `class` attribute coming from the parent component (like `<child class="my-class">`) to a specific node of your child component:

## Vue 3

It is easy in Vue 3 since it will be available via `$attrs`.
You just need to [`v-bind="$attrs"`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance-on-multiple-root-nodes) on the child element you want this in.
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#class-and-style-merging

You would then have that class duplicated on the parent node if you have a single root node: https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#attrs

> By default, everything in $attrs will be automatically inherited on the component's root element if there is only a single root element.
> Blockquote

To prevent this you can add [`inheritAttrs: false`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance) to your child component so it does not get any attributes from parent on the root node.

If you have multi-root elements [you don't need this](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance-on-multiple-root-nodes).

---

## Vue 2

It is not as straightforward since the `class` and `style` attributes are [not available through `$attrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs) in Vue 2 (the rest of the HTML attributes are there, and all props are available in `$props`).

I have solved it by accessing the classes in `this.$vnode.data.staticClass` from the child component, and adding `v-bind="{ class: $vnode.data.staticClass }"` to the node you want the class to be added on.

Vue 2 is legacy, so not so important now :man_shrugging:

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the template structure of your ChildComponent

Your Parent Component can look like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <InputField  class="anyClass" />
</div>
```

If your Child looks like this:

```
<template>
   <input ... />
</template
```

Because if you have only 1 root Element in your template this will inherit the classes given automatically.

if your Template e.g. looks like this: (only available in vue3)

```
<template>
   <input v-bind="$attrs" />
   <span> hi </span>
</template
```

You will need the `v-bind="$attrs"` so Vue knows where to put the attributes to. Another Solution would be giving `classes` as props and assigning it to the element with `:class="classes"`

Comment: This works, but if you have a root element that you do not want to be styled then you will have duplicate styles as expected `<ChildComponent class="myClass" />` will set `myClass` to root and node with `v-bind="$attrs"`

Comment: @MrEduar in this case you can set `inheritAttrs: false` to avoid parents inherits the classes. source: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance

Comment: The bad thing about that is that you can't use `<script setup>.`

Answer (score 2):

In Vue2, the child's root element receives the classes.

If you need to pass them to a specific element of your child component, you can read those classes from the root and set them to a specific element.

Example of a vue child component:

```
<template>
    <div ref="root">
        <img ref="img" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners" :class="classes"/>
    </div>
</template>

export default {


    data() {
        return {
            classes: null,
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.classes = this.$refs.root.getAttribute("class")
        this.$refs.root.removeAttribute("class")
    },
}
```

Pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for the customs form component in Vue 2 where the props go to a child element looks something like this.

````html
<template>
  <div class="input-field">
    <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
    <input
      :value="value"
      :class="inputClass"
      @input="updateValue"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      v-on="listeners"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    value: [String, Number],
    inputClass: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  computed: {
    listeners() {
      return {
        ...this.$listeners,
        input: this.updateValue,
      };
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(event) {
      this.$emit("input", event.target.value);
    },
  },
};
</script>

The usage of those components could look something like this.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <InputField
      v-model="name"
      label="What is your name?"
      type="text"
      class="custom"
      inputClass="input-custom"
    />
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InputField from "./components/InputField";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    InputField,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
    };
  },
};
</script>
````

A demo is available here

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-custom-input-field-4vldv?file=/src/components/InputField.vue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [vue props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) . Like this:

child component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <input :class="className" type="text" value="Test" v-bind="$attrs" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props:{
    className:{
      type:String,
      default:'',
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

Parent component:

```js
 <div id="app">
    <InputField  :class-name="'custom-class'" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Can it be done without props? and utilizing v-bind="$attrs"? since if I'm using custom prop I'm loosing intelisense when using tailwind

Comment: I'm not sure about that and it's hard to debug for me. Do you get `custom-class` in your child component as attrs? you could check via Vue dev tools. I think you could start your debugging from there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using vue2 the `v-bind=$attrs` is being hooked to the root element of your component the `<div>` tag. Check the [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/attrs-includes-class-style.html#_2-x-behavior). You can put this wrapper on the parent element if you need it or just get rid of it.

Here is a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-meitner-oyu93?file=/src/components/InputField.vue)

**Another approach**

There is also the idea of taking the classes from the parent and passing it to the child component with a `ref` after the component is `mounted`

Parent Element:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <InputField class="custom-class" ref="inputField" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InputField from "./components/InputField";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    InputField,
  },
  mounted() {
    const inputField = this.$refs.inputField;
    const classes = inputField.$el.getAttribute("class");
    inputField.setClasses(classes);
  },
};
</script>
```

Child Element:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Test" :class="classes" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      classes: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setClasses: function (classes) {
      this.classes = classes;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-chaum-7eu61?file=/src/components/InputField.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue 3.3.11 (December 2023), this approach works for me:

```
<template>
    <h1>Parent component</h1>
    <MyCustom class="foo" />
</template>
```

And then:

```
<template>
    <h2>Multi-root component</h2>
    <div :class="$attrs.class">
        Hello
    </div>
</template>
```

Using `$attrs.class` inside the template will give you direct access to the parent's `class`.

If, within `MyCustom`, you need to access the classes in the JS code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {useAttrs} from 'vue';

const attrs = useAttrs();
console.log(attrs.class); // output the classes passed by parent
</script>
```